# SQL for looping the date and summarize data

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift

I need to summarize by customer having specific product from 2018-1-1 until today if cdate is within activationdt and next_activationdt. When next_activationdt is empty that means it is still in use and not cancelled or changed.

For example 2018-1-1, Mary and Alan are using product A.

[image: INPUT AND OUTPUT]

I could not figure out a good way of running all the dates together.

I need to run the code on SQL workbench pulling data from AWS Redshift database.

Comment: This is called a PIVOT. How many products do you have ?

Comment: SQL queries have fixed columns. So do you know it is four columns, one for product A, one for B, one for C and one for D you want to show? Otherwise you'd have to select all products first, then build a query with one column per product and then run this generated SQL. (Or select rows rather than columns and use an app or Website instead that cares about how to display the data in a grid.)

Comment: What has Amazon Redshift got to do with this? That's just a hosting service right - based on PostgreSQL according to Wiki? Tag with Oracle or PostgreSQL  perhaps.Title/tag doesn't appear to marry?

Comment: tags should be just Redshift and NOT postgres, please edit title and remove "oracle". You need a calendar table with one row per date. and you cannot dynamically pivot. is this your final report or just an intermediate step?

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to generate the dates.  Perhaps you have a calendar table, or you can use something like this:

```
with dates as (
      select dateadd(day, row_number() over (), '2018-01-01'::date) as dte
      from t
      limit 365  -- assumes table has at least 365 rows
     )
select d.dte,
       sum( (product = 'A')::int ) as num_a,
       sum( (product = 'B')::int ) as num_b,
       sum( (product = 'C')::int ) as num_c,
       sum( (product = 'D')::int ) as num_d
from dates d left join
     t
     on d.dte >= t.activationdate and
        (d.dte < t.nextactivationdate or t.nextactivationdate is null)
group by d.dte
order by d.dte;
```